# How to share services across projects in Service Stack?

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

What's the best way to share services among Service Stack projects?

The way I'm currently doing it is to inherit from services that are needed.  For example:

```
// Grabbing a service from another project
public class ServiceA : AnotherNamespace.InAnotherAssembly.ServiceC
{
}

// Grabbing a service from another project
public class ServiceB : AnotherNamespace.InAnotherAssembly.ServiceD
{
}

// Business as usual
public class ServiceX : RestServiceBase<RequestPocoX>
{
    ....
}

// Business as usual
public class ServiceY : RestServiceBase<RequestPocoY>
{
    ....
}
```

This allows Service Stack to wire up all of the services automatically when referencing the assembly in the AppHost

```
public AppHost() : base("Combined Services", typeof(ServiceA).Assembly)
{
}
```

Is this a reasonable approach, or are there better alternatives?

The reason I bring this up is because I ran into an issue trying to ResolveService in "ServiceD".  I think this might be because the IoC couldn't find it.

I hope that's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pass multiple assemblies to the constructor:

```
public AppHost()
    : base("Combined Services", 
        typeof(ServiceX).Assembly, 
        typeof(ServiceD).Assembly)
{
}
```

Comment: Is this a recent addition to SS?  I don't recall being able to do that in the past.

Comment: @JeffMitchell the signature has had `params Assembly[]` for years.